# I can't get the response from BreweryDB API to show in my simple app

Tags: angularjs

I am working with the BreweryDB API and I can't even get the response to show in my simple app.

Here is the app.js file that houses the controller. I am simply using a HTTP GET to load the API data.

```
angular.module('BreweryGuideApp', [])
  .controller('BreweryGuideController', function($scope, $http){
    var pendingTask;

    if($scope.search === undefined){
      $scope.search = "300 Suns Brewing"; // init search bar data
      fetch(); // call fetch function
    }

    $scope.change = function(){
      if(pendingTask){
        clearTimeout(pendingTask);
      }
      pendingTask = setTimeout(fetch, 800);
    };

    function fetch(){
      $http.get("https://api.brewerydb.com/v2/brewery/x4vqAl?key=cc12540abedfa669021307d4ba111d87&format=json")
       .success(function(response){  $scope.details = response.data; }); //get API response on success
    } //end fetch

  }); // end controller
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title ng-bind="'Brewery.Guide - ' + data.name"></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body ng-app="BreweryGuideApp" ng-controller="BreweryGuideController">
    <div class="container-fluid outerdiv">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b>Brewery.Guide</b> <span class="span-style">Get Yer Drink On</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <noscript>
        <div class="nojs">Javascript is either disabled or not supported in your browser. Please enable it or use a Javascript enabled browser.</div>
      </noscript>

      <div class="animated zoomInRight">
        <div class="input-group search-bar">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="change()" onclick="select()" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter brewery name" autofocus />
          <span class="input-group-addon bar-style"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div id="main-info" ng-include="'partials/main-info.html'" class="col-md-8"></div>

        <div id="related-results" ng-include="'partials/related-results.html'" class="col-md-4 animated bounce related-results"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the `main-info.html` to be inserted using the `ng-include` directive:

```
<div ng-if="details.status!=verified">
  Loading results...
</div>

<div ng-if="data.status==verified">
  <span class="span-outer">
    {{ data.status }}
    <a href="{{ data.website }}" target="_blank">{{ data.name }}</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the data that I get from the URL I am using in app.js:

```
{
  "message":"Request Successful",
  "data":{
    "id":"x4vqAl",
    "name":"300 Suns Brewing",
    "description":"300 Suns Brewing was really just an idea brought up years ago, that kept surfacing every time a brewery was toured, a GABF was attended, a new craft beer was tasted, a bottle of homebrew was shared on the back deck in the cool summer evening air. It was just a dream and one day (gulp), we worked up the nerve to make it a reality. We wanted to put our time and our work into something that brought joy to others the way those moments brought joy to us. And we wanted to give our community very meaningful ways that they could become part of the shaping of our brewery.",
    "website":"http:\/\/www.300sunsbrewing.com",
    "established":"2014",
    "isOrganic":"N",
    "images":{
      "icon":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/x4vqAl\/upload_fI8k35-icon.png",
      "medium":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/x4vqAl\/upload_fI8k35-medium.png",
      "large":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/brewerydbapi\/brewery\/x4vqAl\/upload_fI8k35-large.png"
    },
    "status":"verified",
    "statusDisplay":"Verified",
    "createDate":"2014-05-05 12:24:15",
    "updateDate":"2015-08-14 16:49:36"
  },
  "status":"success"
}
```

Very simple, but I can't even get it to load any data. The search input field is really irrelevant, but I included it in case that might be causing an issue.

Comment: Did you test the `GET` api? Do you receive a `json` data from the `API`?

Comment: yes, see above. I used the URL from app.js.

Answer (score 0):

You refer `details` as `data` in HTML. However, in the controller.js, you don't have any variable like `$scope.data`. So that's why you cannot load the data. In order to let `HTML`or template can access the variable, you can declare the variable in `$scope.` (using $scope dot notation) format.

Because you are using `$http().success()` method, it returns you the data, so you don't do `$scope.details = response.data`, instead, you should do `$scope.details = response`;

Controller.js

```
function fetch(){
  $http.get("https://api.brewerydb.com/v2/brewery/x4vqAl?key=cc12540abedfa669021307d4ba111d87&format=json")
   .success(function(data) {  
     $scope.details = data; 
   });
} //end fetch
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="details.status!=verified">
  Loading results...
</div>

<div ng-if="details.status==verified">
  <span class="span-outer">
    {{ details.status }}
    <a href="{{ details.website }}" target="_blank">{{ details.name }}</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Shaohao, Thx for the reply. But I've tried it both ways and neither one works. I did update the app.js file with your changes and still nothing.

Comment: Can you update the `app.js` file, so that I can see what changes you made? And after you update, do you get any error?

Comment: One more thing, here is example data from the API when using the URL that I am using in app.js.

Comment: Can you post the example data as well?

Comment: I made some changes to the answer? try it